# Does AWS take down each availability zones(A-Z) or whole regions for maintenance

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

AWS has a maintenance window for each region.
**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/maintenance-window.html** but could not find any documentation about how it works with multiple A-Z in the same region.

I have a Redis cache configured and have a replica on different(A-Z) in the same region.   The whole purpose of configuring replica on different(A-Z) if one (A-Z) is not available serve it from next(A-Z)
When they doing maintenance are they take down the whole region or individual availability zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the FAQ on ElastiCache maintenance https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/elasticache-maintenance/

This says that if you have a multi AZ deployment, it will take down the instances one at a time triggering a fail-over to the read replica, and then create new instances before taking down the rest so you should not experience any interruptions in your service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @morras for the above [link](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/elasticache-maintenance/) and explains how elasticache works maintenance window period. Below 3 question I have taken out from the above link and explain about it.

**1. How long does a node replacement take?**

*A replacement typically completes within a few minutes. The replacement may take longer in certain instance configurations and traffic patterns. For example, Redis primary nodes may not have enough free memory, and may be experiencing high write traffic. When an empty replica syncs from this primary, the primary node may run out of memory trying to address the incoming writes as well as sync the replica. In that case, the master disconnects the replica and restarts the sync process. It may take multiple attempts for replica to sync successfully. It is also possible that replica may never sync if the incoming write traffic continues to remains high.*

Memcached nodes do not need to sync during replacement and are always replaced fast irrespective of node sizes.

**2. How does a node replacement impact my application?**

*For Redis nodes, the replacement process is designed to make a best effort to retain your existing data and requires successful Redis replication. For single node Redis clusters, ElastiCache dynamically spins up a replica, replicates the data, and then fails over to it. For replication groups consisting of multiple nodes, ElastiCache replaces the existing replicas and syncs data from the primary to the new replicas. If Multi-AZ or Cluster Mode is enabled, replacing the primary triggers a failover to a read replica. If Multi-AZ is disabled, ElastiCache replaces the primary and then syncs the data from a read replica. The primary will be unavailable during this time.
For Memcached nodes, the replacement process brings up an empty new node and terminates the current node. The new node will be unavailable for a short period during the switch. Once switched, your application may see performance degradation while the empty new node is populated with cache data.*

**3. What best practices should I follow for a smooth replacement experience and minimize data loss?**

*For Redis nodes, the replacement process is designed to make a best effort to retain your existing data and requires successful Redis replication. We try to replace just enough nodes from the same cluster at a time to keep the cluster stable. You can provision primary and read replicas in different availability zones. In this case, when a node is replaced, the data will be synced from a peer node in a different availability zone. For single node Redis clusters, we recommend that sufficient memory is available to Redis, as described here. For Redis replication groups with multiple nodes, we also recommend scheduling the replacement during a period with low incoming write traffic.
For Memcached nodes, schedule your maintenance window during a period with low incoming write traffic, test your application for failover and use the ElastiCache provided "smarter" client. You cannot avoid data loss as Memcached has data purely in memory.*